# Sumar vectores, meterlo en otro e imprimirlo en MIPS

Tags: array, ensamblador

Somos dos estudiantes y nos gustaría resolver esta duda que nos ha surgido.
Nos surge la duda de cómo podemos guardar el resultado del calculo entre cada elemento de dos vectores en otro vector. El imprimirlo creemos que lo hacemos bien. os pongo por aquí nuestro código, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

este es el área de datos

```
.data

   A: .word 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
   B: .word 0x01, 0x02, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x20, 0x100, 0x2000
   C: .space 32
```

ahora el area de código

```
.text
li $t0, 0 #contador de Bucle
li $t5, 0 #contador de imprimir
li $t1, 8 #Limitador
li $t6, 0 #El acumulado


Bucle:
    beq $t0, $t1, imprimir #si t0 == t1 entonces va a imprimir

    #guardamos cada cadena en un registro
    la $s0, A
    la $s1, B
    la $s2, C

    #cargamos el primer valor de cada cadena
    lw $t2, 0($s0)
    lw $t3, 0($s1)

    #operaciones
    add $t4, $t2, $t3
    subi $t4, $t4, 1

    #guardamos en C el contenido de t4
    #sw $t4, 0($s2)
```

creemos que el problema esta justo aqui arriba, con el sw pero claro, no sabemos si no como guardar el resultado en el espacio del vector C

```
    #desplazamos el vector al siguiente vector e incrementamos los contadores
    addi $s0, $s0, 4
    addi $s1, $s1, 4
    addi $s2, $s2, 4
    addi $t0, $t0, 1

    j Bucle

imprimir:

    beq $t5, $t1, fin #si t5 == t1 entonces va a fin
    lw $a0, 0($s2)
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    addi $t5, $t5, 1
    j imprimir

fin:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina. +1 por plantear tu problema de forma correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Creemos que lo resolvimos al final. el problema estaba en que no ponemos el puntero del vector C al principio y que los declarábamos dentro del bucle. Os paso el resultado para que le sirva de ayuda a alguien futuro.

> Aquí está el area de datos

```
.data

   A: .word 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
   B: .word 0x01, 0x02, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x20, 0x100, 0x2000
   C: .space 32
```

> Aquí el de código

```
.text
main:

    #guardamos cada cadena en un registro
    la $a0, A
    la $a1, B
    la $a2, C

    li $t1, 8 #Limitador
    li $t2, 0 #dato del primer vector
    li $t3, 0 #dato del segundo vector
    li $t4, 0 #suma de ambos

Bucle:

    #cargamos el primer valor de cada cadena
    lw $t2, 0($a0)
    lw $t3, 0($a1)

    beq $t1, $zero, salirbucle #si t1 == 0 entonces va a imprimir


    #operaciones
    add $t4, $t2, $t3
    subi $t4, $t4, 1

    #guardamos en C el contenido de t4
    sw $t4, 0($a2)

    #desplazamos el vector al siguiente vector e incrementamos los contadores
    addi $a0, $a0, 4
    addi $a1, $a1, 4
    addi $a2, $a2, 4
    addi $t1, $t1, -1

    j Bucle

salirbucle:

    #Desplazamos el puntero que apuntaba al final del vector hacia el inicio del vector C
    addi $a2, $a2, -32

    #restablecemos el contador
    addi $t1, $t1, 8

imprimir: 

    #cargamos en a0 el valor de C, siendo C el argumento de imprimir un int
    lw $a0, 0($a2)

    beq $t1, $zero, fin #si t5 == t1 entonces va a fin

    #imprimimos con la llamada al sistema
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    #movemos el vector C al siguiente valor 
    addi $a2, $a2, 4
    #restamos uno al contador
    addi $t1, $t1, -1
    j imprimir

fin:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
```